# separate every character in a word

Tags: r, tidyr

I have some data that looks like this (reproducible code at the bottom):

```
  group1 group2
1  ABBBA  ACCCD
```

and I'd like to split every letter into its own sequentially numbered column.

So:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         group1 = c("ABBBA"),
         group2 = c("ACCCD")
)

df %>% separate(group1, sep = c(1, 2), into = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

gets me started:

```
  1 2   3 group2
1 A B BBA  ACCCD
```

and I could type our the rest, but there must be a more elegant way to get what I want which is:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 A B B B A A C C C D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prehaps you can try this (assuming that we may paste group1 and group2 like this on every row)

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     group1 = c("ABBBA","ZY"),
     group2 = c("ACCCD","X")
)

df %>% mutate(id=row_number()
             ,x=str_split(paste0(group1,group2),"(?<=.)(?=.)")) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(k=row_number()) %>%
  spread(k,x)
## A tibble: 2 x 13
## Groups:   id [2]
#  group1 group2    id `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`   `10` 
#  <chr>  <chr>  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 ABBBA  ACCCD      1 A     B     B     B     A     A     C     C     C     D    
#2 ZY     X          2 Z     Y     X     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: This is incredible, but two parts are a bit over my head. When you `unnest` is that because you nested somewhere in the previous `mutate()`?

Comment: Yes indeed : the result of the `str_split` contains a list of every character. To get a row with any one of them, `unnest` is needed.

Comment: and then: `(?<=.)` is `regex` meaning: positive lookbehind any character? followed by `(?=.)` which is: positive lookahead any character? So together it describes a `pattern` for `str_split` that involves splitting into a before and after for every single (`n=inf` by default) position? Sorry, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: For clarity, I suggest adding explicit package needs (the use of `library(tidyverse)` is a bit too broad with its 25 dependencies, for example I have a subset of them installed and prefer to not install all of them unnecessarily). It would be useful to know that this uses (for example) `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `stringr`.